# Opencart 2.0 Unable to login - Admin login loop

Tags: opencart2.x

I am using Opencart 2.1.0.1 on my website. 
Everything was working fine, but now when I try to login to admin it wont show the dashboard but return to the admin screen - a login loop.
Kindly take a look and help me out if you can.. thanks a lot.

I'm trying to solve this for the past 3 days looking at the forums etc but nothing seem to work. There is no SSL. I dont have any Opencart extensions installed, the PHP version is 5.4.45.
Admin login was working fine before.

my .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^system/download/(.*) index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I can list the config files if needed..
Any help appreciated.. thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you tried to clear browser cache? or have tried login with another browser?

Comment: Yes.. I have tried both.. thanks.

Comment: Edit your question and list your `/config.php` & `/admin/config.php` files. Is there any `.htaccess file` in `/admin` folder? Is there any `error_log` generated in `/admin` folder? What's inside `/system/storage/logs/error.log`?

Comment: There was a hack attempt and I suspect some files were compromised.. working on it. Thank you for your replies..